# How to make a Loop over this

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataset with a column with weekly-pay values. And i am trying to change some values using a Loop, for example if i have a value with a length of 2, I convert it to integer and if the length is more than 2, i insert 'Nope'

```
if len (data['V807']) == 2:
  data ['V807']=int(data['V807'])
else:
  data['V807']= 'Nope'
```

The problem is, that it transforms everything to 'Nope', despite the fact that there are many values with length of 2: 
[image: The actual dataset]

And after the loop i have all "Nope"

Answer (score 4):

Your current approach doesn't work, because the `len` in `len(data['V807'])` operates on the *entire column*, not just a particular cell. The `else` bit is executed, and `Nope` is assigned to every cell. Here's the setup -

```
data

               V807
0                33
1                24
2  NOT EMPL->=3 MOS
3    NK-UNASCERTAIN
4                37
```

```
len(data['V807'])
5
```

What you'd need to do, is repeat the process for *every single row* in `data`, and assign values to corresponding cells. Sure, you could use a loop, or a loopy solution with `apply`, but there's a faster way with `to_numeric` -

```
data['V807'] = pd.to_numeric(data['V807'], errors='coerce').fillna('Nope')
data

   V807
0    33
1    24
2  Nope
3  Nope
4    37
```

With the `errors='coerce'` argument, any value that is *not* a numeric type (integer or float) will be converted to `NaN`. After this, use `fillna` to convert `NaN`s to `"Nope"` (although I highly doubt you want this last step, it's a waste because it mixed floats and strings).

Answer (score 3):

We can using `str.isalnum()`(Data from coldspeed :-))

```
df[~df.V807.str.isalnum()]='nope'
df
Out[95]: 
   V807
0    33
1    24
2  nope
3  nope
4    37
```

Comment: Brb, I need to make votes for you. :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ haha, that is fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily using indexing via boolean operators.

```
mask = (df['V807'].str.len() == 2)
mask2 = (df['V807'].str.len() != 2) 

df[mask] = df[mask].astype(int)
df[mask2] = 'Nope'
```